# Независимое текущее время JS

Tags: javascript, время, datetime

Есть таймер нескольких дат на JS и там происходит проверка, где сравнивается текущее время с заданным:

```
    var timeEnds = [ new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 12, 23, 00), // new Date(год, месяц - 1, день, час, минуты);
                     new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 13, 5, 00),
                     new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 13, 19, 30),
                     new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 13, 21, 30),
                     new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 13, 23, 00),
                     new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 14, 4, 00),
                     new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6 - 1, 14, 19, 00),
                     new Date(date.getFullYear() + 1, 6 - 1, 12, 23, 00) ];

    ...

    var timeIndex = 0; // Индекс массива с датами
    var nowdate = new Date(); // Текущее время
    for (var i = 0; i < timeEnds.length; i++) { // Цикл по массиву дат
        if (nowdate > timeEnds[timeIndex]) { // Проверка на наступление даты из массива
            timeIndex++; // Переходим к следующей дате
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Дело в том, что сравнивается текущее время пользователя установленного на ПК. То есть, не учитывается часовой пояс или ситуация, когда у пользователя вообще не правильная дата выставлена. Как решить эту проблему, может есть какие-нибудь библиотеки или сайт который можно парсить?

Comment: http://www.timeapi.org/; 

https://timezonedb.com/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общее независимое время - это unixtime. Unixtime будет одинаковым как для США, так и для РФ и для любой другой страны. Это количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи (по UTC) 1 января 1970 года. В javascript его можно получить следующим образом:

```
parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
```

Просто изначально работайте с unixtime.

Comment: Ответ не связан с проблемой автора никак.

Comment: не решает проблему _когда у пользователя вообще не правильная дата выставлена_